# Get json from the server without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, tornado

I try to make the least request to server, and this is by sending to the client a json file, and then work on this json file,

But, how can I avoid the page from being refreshed? I want that the `json` get received without the refresh of the page:

Here is my js/python file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#latlon").on("submit", function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/latlon",
        data: ("#latlon").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(responseData) {
            alert(responseData)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
        })
    })
    })


class LatLon(MainHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        lat = self.get_argument("lat")
        lon = self.get_argument("lon")
        wwo.request(key=key, q="{},{}".format(lat, lon), format="json", showlocaltime="yes", cc="no", tp=6, extra="isDayTime")
        yield tornado.gen.Task(ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 1)
        self.write(json_encode(wwo.result))
```

I am new to Ajax, and everytime I execute this program, I dont even get my `alert`.
How do I send the chunk without refreshing the page?

NB: there is the method `getJSON` but it needs some **Ready json**?

Comment: Debug your code. There is a $ missing in your second ("#latlon") jQuery selector.

Comment: now that i added it, it waits for me, after i hit ok it refreshs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add  `e.preventDefault();` on your submit event to prevent page refresh.

```
$("#latlon").on("submit", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 // code here
})
```